# Evento de click para thumbnail en dropzone

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css3, dropzone.js

Estoy haciendo uso de la libreria [dropzone](https://www.dropzonejs.com/) y necesito detectar el click en el thumbnail para añadir una descripcion para la imagen y tener un identificador o una relación entre descripcion e imagen, si esto no existe habria alguna manera de personalizar los thumbnails y añadir un nuevo elemento data?

Este es el codigo js y html usado:

```js
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var dropzoneCaseUse = $(".dropzone").dropzone({
       url: "ajaxfile.php",
       success: function (file, response) {
          if(response != 0){
             // Download link
             var anchorEl = document.createElement('a');
             anchorEl.setAttribute('href',response);
             anchorEl.setAttribute('target','_blank');
             anchorEl.innerHTML = "<br>Download";
             file.previewTemplate.appendChild(anchorEl);
          }
       }
    });
    Dropzone.options.dropzoneCaseUse = {
        uploadMultiple: true,
        paramName: "file",
        acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.jpeg",
        clickable: true,
        thumbnailWidth: 200,
        thumbnailHeight: 200,
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        accept: function(file, done) {
            console.log("uploaded"); //debuging the upload
            done();
        },
        init: function() {
         this.on("addedfile", function() {
          if (this.files[1]!=null){
            this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
               }
            });
          }
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.7.1/dropzone.min.css" integrity="sha256-iDg4SF4hvBdxAAFXfdNrl3nbKuyVBU3tug+sFi1nth8=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="dropzone">
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.7.1/dropzone.min.js" integrity="sha256-fegGeSK7Ez4lvniVEiz1nKMx9pYtlLwPNRPf6uc8d+8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya he logrado encontrar la solución, tengo que añadir al file que se acaba de subir un listent y asi detecta el click, asi tambien puedo añadir el data que requiera y enlazar directamente con el campo de crear descripción.

```js
var dropzoneCaseUse;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    dropzoneCaseUse = $("#dropCaseUse").dropzone({
       url: "ajaxfile.php",
       success: function (file, response) {
          if(response != 0){
            var imgName = response;
            file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
             // Download link
             var anchorEl = document.createElement('a');
             anchorEl.setAttribute('href',response);
             anchorEl.setAttribute('target','_blank');
             anchorEl.innerHTML = "<br>Download";
             file.previewTemplate.appendChild(anchorEl);
          }
            // Aqui el listener
            file.previewElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
                console.log(this);
            });
       },
       error: function (file, response) {
       file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-error");
       }
    });

    Dropzone.options.dropzoneCaseUse = {
        uploadMultiple: true,
        paramName: "file",
        acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.jpeg",
        clickable: true,
        thumbnailWidth: 200,
        thumbnailHeight: 200,
        timeout: 180000,
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        accept: function(file, done) {
            console.log("uploaded"); //debuging the upload
            done();
        },
    }

})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.7.1/dropzone.min.css"/>

<div class="dropzone">
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.7.1/dropzone.min.js"></script>
```